# Find and replace {0,} occurrences in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, macros, find-and-replace, wildcards

Are there any alternatives to the concept **{0,}** which is not allowed in MS Word?

For example, if I wanted to replace, by a single abbreviation, the next five terms:

articul

articulo

articula

articulas

articulos

what expression should I use?

Comment: If I wanted to replace, by a single abbreviation, the next three terms:

articul ,

articulo ,

articula , 

what expression can I use? I've tried articul[oa]{0,1}, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question to include your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, you use the `?` wildcard character as the single character wildcard when trying to Find matching words.

So using `articul?` with the *Use wildcards* option selected will match `articul`, `articulo`, and `articula`.

[image]

Comment: sorry, my example was not accurate, so I've edited my question.

Comment: Note that "articul?" will *not* match "articul". Actually it will match "articul " or "articul^p" or similar. The ? wildcard doesn't mean 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Short of VBA the best you can get with the Find and Replace dialog is `<articul*>` with the *Use wildcards* option checked.

This will match all five of your words exactly but unfortunately will also match words like "**articul**ated". If that's not a problem then you should be good to go.