# How to work around the impossibility to find zero or more occurrencies in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, find, find-and-replace, wildcards

How would you proceed about the following find and replace in Microsoft Word?

Find what?

`D.Lgs.`

(that can be any combination of lower or upper case, plus the dots may or may not be there, i.e. I need to find all of the following: dlgs, DLGS, D.Lgs, dlgs, dlgs., etc.)

Replace with what?

`D.Lgs.`

The thing is Microsoft Word won't let me find zero or more occurrencies of a character (in this case, the dot) (see here for more info: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm ).
Using Microsoft Word 2007.

Comment: which word version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace {0,} occurrences in Word](http://superuser.com/questions/923360/find-and-replace-0-occurrences-in-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find your examples with the following wildcard search:

Find:  `[dD][.lL]{1,2}[gG][sS.]{1,2}`
Replace:  `D.Lgs.`

The square brackets limit the characters we're looking for.  By separating them out, we can include the . where it may be (or may not be - ie 0 occurrence).

By including the . (which may or may not be there) with the next expected letter (which will be there), you can use the {1,2} limit to find instances which include just the letter either upper case or lower case (1 character) or the dot followed by letter either upper case or lower case (2 characters).